# Paypal redirect : testing with sandbox account asks to login after redirection

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have created a sandbox account in developer.sandbox.com and in have a buyer account and seller account associated with it.

I am logged in with my sandbox account and when my app(donation form) is redirected to paypal sandbox url, it asks me to signin with a sandbox account.

The same worked a week before but after paypal developer site had an upgrade to BETA version it is causing this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered here ([Paypal Sandbox Testing - Change of URL Endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745626/paypal-sandbox-testing-change-of-url-endpoint))

Basically you need to clear your cache and cookies and ensure the test merchant account you are using has been imported to the new BETA version. Then generate a fresh token and it should work (just worked for me)