# Paypal Sandbox Testing - Change of URL Endpoint?

Tags: php, forms, paypal, sandbox

It seems there are a lot of changes with Paypal Sandbox lately and I am stuck with my testing. Before, we only point to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr for Sandbox testing as seen in the code below:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your bussiness id" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="your item" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="item price" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="Your notify url">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="your return url">
<input type="image" border="0" name="paypal" src="images/btn_paypal_nl.gif" onClick=""/>
</form>
```

But now, Sandbox keeps asking me to "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features." which I assume means I am using the wrong endpoint given the latest Paypal Sandbox changes.

My questions now are:

- Does this still work?
- If yes, "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" is replaced with what?

As of now, I'm assuming that the URL I mentioned above is the only change I need to do. However, I can't find new documentation on what the new URL to submit the form to is. And Paypal doesn't have updated docs about this.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features while using paypal sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826441/please-login-to-use-the-paypal-sandbox-features-while-using-paypal-sandbox)

Comment: not really a duplicate, but a similar one with differing solutions

Comment: Don't worry about that. It turned out to be a different problem, no action will occur until there are sufficient votes. My vote will expire soon without other similar close votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the link "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" still work. But, now you have to use your paypal account credential to login to your paypal.developer acount. If you don't have this then just create one here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts. Your old sandbox login credentials will not work here.  But after logging through your paypal account you can import your old sandbox's personal and business account to here.

Create session in new tab by logging using https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

and if still see sandbox blank page with just sandbox.com name then just clear your cookies and cache an try again.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I already have a new developer account. But I tried clearing my cookies and cache as you mentioned and it worked! Thanks, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your cmd value `_xclick/` -> `_xclick`

Comment: Done. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

When using features of the paypal sandbox, you must first log in to the developer area at https://developer.paypal.com/ to establish a session there. I usually leave it open in a different tab.

---

*edit*

If you had a developer account prior to the recent updates to the developer area, you might have to go in and set up a new sandbox account. I lost access to the sandbox accounts that I had set up, but the API calls still worked.

Check https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts. If you see your old account listed there with a disabled checkbox, or don't see it listed at all, create a new one.

Comment: I am already logged-in but still the same issue => Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features. I did not have this issue with the old Sandbox.

Comment: I was able to successfully import my old Sandbox test accounts (both business and personal). So right now I can see 3 accounts, 1 is the new one automatically created(facilitator) when I shifted to the new system and the other 2 are the ones I imported from the old Sandbox. But I guess this is not the problem. The problem is with the call. I cannot continue on because Sandbox is asking me to login even when I am already logged in! :(

Comment: Try creating a new one, as an experiment. Make sure to change the credentials, then give it a test.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Darn! Let's see if anyone else can come up with something, I'll be back on this evening and can look in to things more if you haven't gotten it worked out. Sorry this didn't help.